# How to format variable number of arguments?

Tags: python, string, format

I have a list of arguments I would like to apply to a list of template format strings. My issue is that each template string can take a variable number of arguments. I want to avoid having a hardcoded list of how many arguments each string takes

```
counts = [1, 0, 2, 3, 1] # How to get rid of this counts list?
arguments = ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g"] 
templates = [
    "{} one",
    "none",
    "{} two {}",
    "{} {} three {}",
    "one2 {}",
]

start = 0
for i, template in enumerate(templates):
    count = counts[i] # a programmatic way to get the count for current template?
    print(template.format(*arguments[start : start + count]))
    start += count
```

**Output:**

> a one
> none
> b two c
> d e three f
> one2 g

How can I apply a list of strings to a list of format templates without knowing how many variables each format requires?

Comment: You might also consider regexing the string, which is probably what Python does under the hood.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could join all your templates using a character that you're unlikely to see in the templates or arguments, do the string interpolation, and then split the result.

```
templates = [
    "{} one",
    "none",
    "{} two {}",
    "{} {} three {}",
    "one2 {}",
    "and {{literal}} braces {{}}"
]
arguments = ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g"] 

joined_template = chr(1).join(templates)

formatted_string = joined_template.format(*arguments)

formatted_templates = formatted_string.split(chr(1))
```

`formatted_templates` is now:

```
['a one',
 'none',
 'b two c',
 'd e three f',
 'one2 g',
 'and {literal} braces {}']
```

Comment: This excludes whatever is used to join the templates from being in a template.

Comment: As mentioned in the first sentence. You're unlikely to see a control character such as `chr(0)` or `chr(1)` in a real-life string though, so it's a decent compromise IMO @pystr

Comment: I'd actually say your issue with this is the same issue you'd see with a single string. You are just creating one long string and then applying your arguments. That is probably fine if you're sure the total number of arguments and template slots are equivalent - and breaks down if you're trying to do anything other than that. Maybe that's fine for this use case, but I am hard pressed to think of the application of that case that wouldn't suggest some other, far more straightforward solution.

Comment: I think I was hoping python offered some way of getting the count. But this seems like the best alternative. I agree with your comments and appreciate both of your answers. Thanks.

Comment: @NathanielFord Of course! After all, you're going to have to provide as many arguments as you asked it to format into your template. The issue with counting pairs of braces is that it can be fooled by literal brace pairs like `{{}}` or when a format specifier is given like `{:0<5}`, and that doesn't happen here because you're depending on python's internal format routines to count the arguments.

Comment: @pystr there might be some way of doing this using the [`string.Formatter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html#string.Formatter) class and its `parse()` and `check_unused_args()` methods, so it could be worth digging into that if you'd _really_ like a rigorous solution.

Comment: Agreed; however doing that count will be hard to avoid if you need some subset of either the templates or arguments, or need to intuit how to arrage the list of one or the other. I'm also hoping that the templates aren't too long... but those are all different questions than what he asked, and the inversion of the problem space you lay out here is a great tool!

Answer (score 2):

Rather than hard coding your count, just [count](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.count) the number of valid braces in each template. A simplistic way of doing this is like this:

```
>>> "{} {} three {}".count("{}")
3
>>> "none".count("{}")
0
```

So your program would look something like this:

```
arguments = ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g"] 
templates = [
    "{{}} one",
    "none",
    "{} two {}",
    "{} {} three {}",
    "one2 {}",
    "and {{literal}} braces {{}}"
]

start = 0
for template in templates:
    count = template.count("{}")
    print(template.format(*arguments[start : start + count]))
    start += count
```

In the REPL:

```
>>> arguments = ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g"]
>>> templates = [
...     "{} one",
...     "none",
...     "{} two {}",
...     "{} {} three {}",
...     "one2 {}",
...     "and {{literal}} braces {{}}"
... ]
>>>
>>> start = 0
>>> for template in templates:
...     count = template.count("{}")
...     print(template.format(*arguments[start : start + count]))
...     start += count
...
{} one
none
b two c
d e three f
one2 g
and {literal} braces {}
```

Comment: This seems like a decent solution but fails for templates with literal braces. "{{}} text {}"

Comment: Hmm... What do you expect that template to output, though? `"{{}}".format("a")` returns `{}`.

Comment: The count of "{{}} text {}" should be 1 not 2 because "{{}} text {}".format() accepts 1 argument not 2. The count of "{{}}" should be 0.

Comment: Yep! Makes sense. This solution won't cover that case, for sure, not without a lot of error checking. In that case, the answer joining the templates and then distributing arguments is probably what you want - unless those counts are incompatible.

Comment: I accepted the joining solution. Thanks for your solution as well nathaniel.!